# Overriding Commutative Operations For Same Class Operands in Python

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading, overloading

I am trying to understand how operator overriding works for two operands of a custom class.

For instance, suppose I have the following:

```
class Adder:
    def __init__(self, value=1):
        self.data = value
    def __add__(self,other):
        print('using __add__()')
        return self.data + other
    def __radd__(self,other):
        print('using __radd__()')
        return other + self.data
```

I initialize the following variables:

```
x = Adder(5)
y = Adder(4)
```

And then proceed to do the following operations:

```
1 + x
using __radd__()
Out[108]: 6

x + 2
using __add__()
Out[109]: 7
```

The two operations above seem straigtforward. If a member of my custom class is to the right of the "+" in the addition expression, then `__radd__` is used. If it is on the left, then `__add__` is used. This works for expressions when one operand is of the `Adder` type and another one is something else.

When I do this, however, I get the following result:

```
x + y
using __add__()
using __radd__()
Out[110]: 9
```

As you can see, if both operands are of the custom class, then both `__add__` and `__radd__` are called.

My question is how does Python unravel this situation and how is it able to call both the right-hand-addition function, as well as the left-hand-addition function.

Comment: It is my understanding that `5+y` should call `y.__radd__(5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because inside your methods you add the data to `other`. This is itself an instance of Adder. So the logic goes:

- call `__add__` on x;
- add `x.data` (an int) to y (an Adder instance)
- ah, right-hand operand is an instance with a `__radd__` method, so
- call `__radd__` on y;
- add int to `y.data` (another int).

Usually you would check to see if `other` was an instance of your class, and if so add `other.data` rather than just `other`.

Answer (score 1):

That's the because the implementation of your `__add__` and `__radd__` method do not give any special treatment to the instances of the `Adder` class. Therefore, each `__add__` call leads to an *integer plus Adder instance* operation which further requires `__radd__` due to the Adder instance on the right side.

You can resolve this by doing:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    print('using __add__()')
    if isinstance(other, Adder):
        other = other.data
    return self.data + other

def __radd__(self, other):
    print('using __radd__()')
    return self.__add__(other)
```

Comment: This makes sense. Are you saying that when Python encounters the instance of `Adder` on the right side instead of an integer, then it does some wodoo magic to make it an integer?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Wouldn't call it [magic](https://xkcd.com/628/). How would you expect `5 + y` be resolved after the first `x.__add__(y)`  call?

Comment: That is the part I am confused about. How can you enter `__add__` and return from it without getting the entire answer for the expression of the type `a + b`? Does `__add__` somehow parses the first operand and determines that it is `x=5` and then bounces the result `5 + y` to the `__radd__` method?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Did you read DanielRoseman's answer? Pretty much explains it. `__add__` calls `__radd__` to resolve the ambiguous *int + Adder instance*.